# fetch is not working in react native on android

Tags: react-native

can someone help me, please? I am a beginner in react-native I am doing a registration page and login page, I successfully use the fetch to make a network call on IOS but not on android, please Help me 
here is the fetch method code:

```
const json = JSON.stringify(payload);
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    body: json
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(() => {
    // alert('Success! You may now log in.');
    // Redirect to home screen
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
})
.catch((error) => {
    alert("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création de votre compte.");
})
.done()
```

Comment: @Amatdou, I see your code is correct, which error shows? please show the error info

Answer (score 0):

```
return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

          console.log("response data" , responseJson)
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code is correct, and it is successful on ios but not android, it may you don not add permission on android AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

if you url is `http://..`, you also have add allow to http request. About this more, you can read this [blog](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....
```

Comment: I added it in the AndroidManifest file but it still does not work.<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.authapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application 
      
  
      android:name=".MainApplication" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false" 
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      >...</application>

</manifest>

Comment: i am facing the same issue. @Amadou how did you get around the issue?